# Set Pixelratio in Gimp to 0.5mm x 0.75mm

Tags: gimp

I have to paint some pictures for a small display of a micro controller. The Display has a resolution of 128x64 Pixel. But the Pixel aren't a square. They have a width of **0.5 mm** and a height of **0.75mm**. All my nice drawn images in **GIMP** look ugly on this display.

Can i change the ratio of drawn pixel in **GIMP** so i can see the image the same way like on my micro controller screen? Is there a setting for this or do i need to use my imagination?

I've looked around in settings menu but found nothing ...

thx in advanced

PS: Wrong Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Image>Print size` to set a different definition for the vertical and horizontal axis (don't forget to "unlink" the two entry fields otherwise changing one will change the other).

Then **untick `View>Dot for dot`** so that Gimp no longer maps image pixels to screen pixels and displays the images with their intended definition (and aspect ratio in your case).